# as3 Getting Response of a http Head request

Tags: http, actionscript-3, http-headers

I'm trying to Read the response of a http Head method request but i don't get anything as the response of head requests doesn't contains a body but i need to get the ['content-length'] which is a header returned
this is my code

```
function GetSize() {
        var request: URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.HEAD;
        var loader: URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, DownloadFileSize, false, 0, true);

        loader.load(request);
    }
    function DownloadFileSize(ev: Event) {
        trace("the answer is :"+(URLLoader)(ev.currentTarget).data);
    }
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: `EVENT.COMPLETE` is just one of many events `URLLoader` can emit. For Example the [HTTPStatusEvent.httpResponseStatus](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#event:httpResponseStatus) which possesses a property called `responseHeaders`. Give that one a try.

Comment: @DodgerThud  thanks it worked for me! post it as answer ,and ill tick it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EVENT.COMPLETE` is just one of many events URLLoader can emit. For Example it can also emit [HTTPStatusEvent.httpResponseStatus](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#event:httpResponseStatus) which possesses a property called `responseHeaders`. Give that one a try.

Here's the example code provided by the documentation for [HttpStatusEvent](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/HTTPStatusEvent.html#includeExamplesSummary)

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.HTTPStatusEvent;

public class HTTPStatusEventExample extends Sprite {

    public function HTTPStatusEventExample() {
        var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);

        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.[yourDomain].com/MissingFile.html");
        loader.load(request);
    }

    private function httpStatusHandler(event:HTTPStatusEvent):void {
        trace("httpStatusHandler: " + event);
        trace("status: " + event.status);
    }
}
```

}

And for your usecase (obtaining the headers):

```
private function httpStatusHandler(event:HTTPStatusEvent):void {
        for(var i:int = 0;i<event.responseHeaders.length;i++){
            trace(i.toString() + ":" + event.responseHeaders[i].name + " - " + event.responseHeaders[i].value);
        }
}
```

I haven't tested this code, but according to your comment this approach is working.